# What causes "Code by Zapier" trigger to run independently?

Tags: zapier

I get how to use [Code by Zapier](https://zapier.com/help/code/) as an *action* within a zap, but how do you use it as a *trigger*? I can set it up easily, but I am confused as to how & when the zap actually knows to start running on it's own? In other words, what tells the zap to start running? In other triggers typically it's a webhook sent to Zapier, but there are no webhooks involved with "Code by Zapier."

[image: Code by Zapier as trigger]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your plan, the Zap will run the JavaScript code every 5 or 10 minutes. You must return an array of objects with unique "ID" parameters for it to actually run the actions on those items. You'll want to take a look at the documentation for more details, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: Thank you. I must have missed that message after turning on the zap. > "While on, this Zap will automagically check for your Code by Zapier Run Javascript every 5 minutes."